# Managing external JARs build paths in git controlled eclipse project created in Ubuntu and cloned in Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, ubuntu-12.04, buildpath

I am having an eclipse project created on Ubuntu, in which all the JARs that I am using, are located in a folder `/home/xyz/AllJARs`. Here the `/home` is the system home folder. The project as well as the AllJARs folder is git version controlled on a central git server.
 

So, all the paths to these JARs in the project's build path are /home/xyz/AllJARs. When I'm cloning the project repo and the AllJARs repo on a Windows machine, I'm shown errors related to build path since it can't find the path /home/xyz/AllJARs.
How can I manage this situation where I can have external JAR files in build paths which can work on Ubuntu as well as on a Windows machine? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two easy options:

1. **use relative paths:** for example, put the JAR folder in the folder above your project, then you can set the JARs' paths to `../AllJARs/`
2. **put JARs into project:** you can also just put the JARs into the project folder; if you've set them up as "External JARs" in project settings, you'll have to remove them from that list, and re-add them with "Add JARs". Eclipse will then look for them locally in the project folder. If you don't want to commit the JARs to the git repo (size and/or permission being a problem), you can just copy them into the Project folder after cloning. While they're not there, you'll be shown a warning, but once Eclipse can find them, everything's fine.